# JPA hibernate not storing child entities in a OneToMany association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm quite new to java persistence.
My database model has two tables: Student and Contact, where each student can have many emergency contacts, but each contact can only belong to one student.

In my controller, the post body is correctly deserealised into a student object which contains a list of contacts objects. **However, nothing is being added into the Contact table**, and nothing in the Student table is added to give the implication that this student can reference a list of contacts. There may a simple solution to this but after hours of searching I couldn't find it.

Controller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void submitStudents(@RequestBody Map<Long,Student> students) {
        System.out.println("==========Updating database==========");
        students.values().forEach(student -> {
            System.out.println(student.getContacts().get(0).getParentTitle());
            studentRepository.save(student);});
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
@Entity(name="Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastNames;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Contact.class, mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    // Spring needs a no-args constructor
    public Student() {}

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastNames() {
        return lastNames;
    }

    public void setLastNames(String lastNames) {
        this.lastNames = lastNames;
    }

    // not sure if I really need this, contacts were added to the student object before I had this method
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("adding contact");
        contact.setStudent(this);
        contacts.add(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }

        return
            this.id == ((Student) object).getId();
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    private String phone;

    public Contact() {}

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        System.out.println("setting student to "+student);
        this.student = student;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Long getId() { return id; }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about cascading, and about the difference between the owner and the inverse sides of an association. JPA needs to be learnt. Read the Hibernate manual, or a good book about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Hibernate to cascade by adding the CascadeType to the @OneToMany:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Contact.class, mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```